# TimePicker is returning only the current time, not the one which is chosen

Tags: android

I have created a TimePicker popup activity, but the problem is that the variables th and tm are initialized to current time and not the time chosen in the TimePicker. I have used getCurrentHour() and getCurrentMinute() to set them and I can't use getHour() and getMinute() as I have set the minimum as 17 as to that of requried 23 for the later. What's going wrong over here?

This is the code

```
public class TimePickerPopup extends Activity {

String th, tm;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.time_picker);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * .8), (int) (height * .7));

    TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.time_picker1);

    th = timePicker.getCurrentHour().toString();
    tm = timePicker.getCurrentMinute().toString();

    ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.select);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
            resultIntent .putExtra("extra",th + " : " + tm);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: move `    th = timePicker.getCurrentHour().toString();
    tm = timePicker.getCurrentMinute().toString();` inside the onclick

Comment: Ya that worked... that was so silly of me. Thanks alot !!